# C#/Restsharp: HTTP Error 417 Expectation failed

Tags: c#, http, restsharp

I have this code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

RestClient = new RestClient(baseUri);
RestClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.domain.tld:8888");
RestClient.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc", "abc");
RestClient.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

// Receive JSESSIONID
var req = new RestRequest("scs/result/resultinfo.jsp", Method.GET);
var res = RestClient.Execute(req); // This request works

// Login
req = new RestRequest("scs/result/j_security_check", Method.POST);
req.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

req.AddParameter("j_username", username, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
req.AddParameter("j_password", password, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

res = RestClient.Execute(req); // This request fails
```

The POST request results in an HTTP error 417: Expectation failed, even `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false`

Can you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Generically the server cannot honor the passed expectations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the XML code above to every `App.config` within my solution helped.

```
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: "Found the solution. Even this didn't work:"       So you found the solution,  but then said Even this didn't work.   I'm so confused....

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I never used RestSharp until a new project with it came my way.

```
StatusCode =  ExpectationFailed
```

So this is the 417 expectation failed error.  Too bad it was not that easy to troubleshoot.

The problem was that the **connectionstring** was missing from the **machine.config** ( project was not using web.config / app.config for several things)

Fixed for me.